# Excel Product Comparison Matrix and Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slicers

I have a data source like below:

```
Product  Feature-1    Feature-2    Price
-----------------------------------------
P1         Y             N          100
P2         N             Y          200
```

I want to represent the same with slicer having:

```
Feature-1
Feature-2
```

So, when I select Feature-1 in slicer, it filters products that has "Y" for Feature-1 and when Feature-2 is selected in the slicer, it filters products that has "Y" for Feature-2:

```
Product   Price              Slicer --> Feature-1
P1         10
```

I couldn't find any customization for slicers. Any help is appreciated.

Note: suggestions on different way of representing other than pivot are also welcome.

Comment: You can use filter in the pivot table, however you would have a huge list of filters if you have a lot of 'features'.

Comment: yea the features list will be huge. If I am able to achieve this, I am planning on multi-level slicer kind based on feature categories.